# How can I speed up this really basic python script for offsetting lines of numbers

Tags: python, performance, math, optimization, large-files

I have a simple text file which contains numbers in ASCII text separated by spaces as per this example.

```
150604849   
319865.301865 5810822.964432 -96.425797 -1610
319734.172256 5810916.074753 -52.490280 -122
319730.912949 5810918.098465 -61.864395 -171
319688.240891 5810889.851608 -0.339890 -1790
*<continues like this for millions of lines>*
```

basically I want to copy the first line as is, then for all following lines I want to offset the first value (x), offset the second value (y), leave the third value unchanged and offset and half the last number.

I've cobbled together the following code as a python learning experience (apologies if it crude and offensive, truly I mean no offence) and it works ok. However the input file I'm using it on is several GB in size and I'm wondering if there's ways to speed up the execution. Currently for a 740 MB file it takes 2 minutes 21 seconds

```
import glob

#offset values
offsetx = -306000
offsety = -5806000

files = glob.glob('*.pts')
for file in files:
    currentFile = open(file, "r")
    out = open(file[:-4]+"_RGB_moved.pts", "w")
    firstline = str(currentFile.readline())
    out.write(str(firstline.split()[0]))

    while 1:
        lines = currentFile.readlines(100000)
        if not lines:
            break
        for line in lines:
            out.write('\n')
            words = line.split()
            newwords = [str(float(words[0])+offsetx), str(float(words[1])+offsety), str(float(words[2])), str((int(words[3])+2050)/2)]              
            out.write(" ".join(newwords))
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `.readlines()`. Use the file directly as an iterator:

```
for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as currentfile, open(file[:-4]+"_RGB_moved.pts", "w") as out:
        firstline = next(currentFile)
        out.write(firstline.split(None, 1)[0])

        for line in currentfile:
            out.write('\n')
            words = line.split()
            newwords = [str(float(words[0])+offsetx), str(float(words[1])+offsety), words[2], str((int(words[3]) + 2050) / 2)]              
            out.write(" ".join(newwords))
```

I also added a few Python best-practices, and you don't need to turn `words[2]` into a float, then back to a string again.

You could also look into using the `csv` module, it can handle splitting and rejoining lines in C code:

```
import csv

for file in files:
    with open(file, "rb") as currentfile, open(file[:-4]+"_RGB_moved.pts", "wb") as out:
        reader = csv.reader(currentfile, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

        out.writerow(next(reader)[0])

        for row in reader:
            newrow = [str(float(row[0])+offsetx), str(float(row[1])+offsety), row[2], str((int(row[3]) + 2050) / 2)]              
            out.writerow(newrow)
```

Comment: sorry, deleted my previous comment as it was incomplete and i did some more testing. let me try again.

Thanks for the help. Its much appreciated. 
It seems that the non-CSV code offers a 14% speed increase which is great!

Original Code - 2:17
Non-CSV code - 2:00
CSV Code - 2:26

Would anyone like to offer any further recommendations?

Comment: Right, so the additional work done to detect quoting actually slows things down. You can try setting `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` (as a keyword argument to both the reader and writer) to save that overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Use thé CSV package.  It may be more optimized than your script and will simplify your code.